# Getting a console or error log from a Cocotron app

Tags: console, cocotron

Does anyone know how to get a console or error log in Cocotron? In XCode if you go to preferences and under debugging you can select start console on startup but when you run the cocotron outside of XCode (in windows) no console pops up.  I would like to try and get the frame rate but I don't know how to output to the console.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I spent **ages** trying to find this out. 
Its very simple once you know it: just add -mconsole to the "Other linker flags" (where you have already added -mwindows)